How to connect mirror maker 2 runing on kafka connect to kafka with SASL_PLAINTEXT authentication
I want to configure syncing message from Cluster A to Cluster B kafka. I am using kafka mirror maker 2 running on kafka connect. When I configure hearbeat connector, I got the error as follow:
[2024-04-25 09:18:27,703] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=1] Failed authentication with /10.110.69.26 (channelId=10.110.69.26:9093-10.110.69.26:37596-57118) (errorMessage=Unexpected Kafka request of type METADATA during SASL handshake.) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
This is configurator of heartbeat connector
`{
    "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
    "heartbeats.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "trace.records.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "target.cluster.alias": "target-0",
    "source.cluster.alias": "source-0",
    "name": "mirror-heartbeat-connector",
    "target.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "10.110.69.26:9093",
    "target.cluster.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username='admin' password='admin!@#';",
    "target.cluster.security.protocol": "SASL_PLAINTEXT",
    "target.cluster.sasl.mechanism": "SCRAM-SHA-512",
    "source.cluster.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username='admin' password='admin!@#';",
    "source.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "10.110.69.25:9093",
    "source.cluster.security.protocol": "SASL_PLAINTEXT",
    "source.cluster.sasl.mechanism": "SCRAM-SHA-512"
}`

Please help me!
I tried change target.cluster.sasl.jaas.config to org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"admin\" password=\"admin!@#\";
But It doesn't work properly.
